# Define 3 heights and use resize in CSS

Tags: css, resize, height, scrollable

I have a div element with to `resize:vertical` style on it. The contents of the div are generated, so it could be empty or filled. The div needs a max height, so that the height increases as new items are added, but it caps the size at 150px and makes the div scrollable.
I could easily accomplish that with the `max-height` style, but if I want to resize it, it doesn't work.

The second idea I had, was to just use the `height` style, but by doing this, the div's not adjusting its height if the contents are smaller than 150px.

Is there any way of doing this without javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible without JavaScript and even if it would be: What do you want this for? Please take a look at [browser support of `resize`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp)!

(What do you mean by "filled" - is this done via PHP or JS? Actually no matter which one you use, you could check if there is any content and if so add an `.empty` class to the `div`)

Comment: Then I'd go for my proposed solution - add some accessibility by adding classes and btw: There are other users that don't use Chrome.